# Convert all my values in array to float python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Numpy and I have a matrix like the following:

```
[["5","6"],
["3","4.5"]]
```

How can I convert all these values to float?

Answer (score 2):

Try `numpy.ndarray.astype(float)`. Read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

> NOTE: This is not an in place operation so remember to set it back to a variable

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([["5","6"],
                ["3","4.5"]])

arr = arr.astype(float)  #<--- 

print(arr)
print(type(arr[0,0])) #printing type of a single element in the matrix
```

```
array([[5. , 6. ],
       [3. , 4.5]])

<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it inplace without extra lib/module:

```
ll = [["5","6"], ["3","4.5"]]

def transform(ll):
    for i in range(len(ll)):
        if type(ll[i])==str:
            ll[i]=float(ll[i])
        elif type(ll[i])==list:
            transform(ll[i])
    return ll

print(transform(ll))
```

output is:

```
[[5.0, 6.0], [3.0, 4.5]]
```

Comment: while a valid approach, OP is using NumPy array already (as mentioned in question and tag), so it's not an extra module.

Comment: right, but code was incomplete in the question